Implementation of interfaces inherited from another interface
I have a base interface
public interface IBase
{
    public IReadOnlyReactiveProperty<bool> BaseBool { get; }
}

Then I inherit this interface
public interface IDoSomething1 : IBase
{
}

public interface IDoSomething2 : IBase
{
}

Then I'm implementing this two interfaces
public class Implementation : IDoSomething1, IDoSomething2
{
    public IReadOnlyReactiveProperty<bool> BaseBool { get; }
}

I get that these two interfaces have the same BaseBool implementation, but they need to have different implementations since the activation logic of these two interfaces may be different.
Because in another class I'm looking for all the IBase type interfaces and subscribe to BaseBool.
In the current form, it turns out that I cannot separate the interfaces IDoSomething1 and IDoSomething2 since they have the same name of the base variable. I need to separate these two interfaces somehow. These interfaces should remain in the same class.
I'm expecting
public class Implementation : IDoSomething1, IDoSomething2
{
    public IReadOnlyReactiveProperty<bool> IDoSomething1.BaseBool { get; }
    public IReadOnlyReactiveProperty<bool> IDoSomething2.BaseBool { get; }
}

But it doesn't work.

Which implementation do you expect to be used if I write (new Implementation() as IBase).BaseBool?

I used Zenject and i have only one "Implementation". I will not create another "Implementation".
Container.BindInterfacesTo().AsSingle();
In another class i want receive two interfaces
public АnotherСlass(IDoSomething1 _doSomething1, IDoSomething2 _doSomething2)
{}

Classic diamond inheritance problem, and the reason why this is impossible. When the IL is generated, it actually effectively generates something like BaseBool implements IBase.BaseBool

You can't use explicit interface implementation here because the property doesn't explicitly belong to the interfaces you're implementing directly. You can only explicitly implement an interface your class is implementing directly, not an interface that acts as a base to the one you implement.
